# Tensorflow accuracy is 0.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm working on an application that should predict interesting moments in audio files with a length of 10 seconds. I converted each 50ms of audio to a note, so each my record has 1 label (1,0 - interesting or not) and 200 note features. Then I created 200 train examples:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
from google.colab import drive
import functools
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

def get_dataset(file_path):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size=12
      label_name='label',
      na_value='?',
      num_epochs=1,
      ignore_errors=False)
  return dataset

train = get_dataset('/content/gdrive/My Drive/myProject/train.csv')
test = get_dataset('/content/gdrive/My Drive/myProject/test.csv')

feature_columns = []

for number in range(200):
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column('note' + str(number + 1) ))

preprocessing_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    preprocessing_layer,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train, epochs=20)
```

Then my model returns such output on 20 epoch:

```
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6959 - acc: 0.5000
```

> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But, don't you think your training data is small?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh yes, I was thinking about it. Is there a formula that describes minimum amount of examples depending on features count?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Where is the model.compile() line? cant seem to find it in the code. Should include the optimizer, loss and accuracy function you are using to train the model.

Comment: @KrisR89 thanks, I fixed the question description

Comment: you have a very insignificant amount of training data, you would need to be unimaginably lucky to happen upon a decent set of weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `tf.nn.softmax` activation hence a single class is correct for each prediction, therefor you should be using `categorical_crossentropy` instead of `binary_crossentropy` as loss function. I don't know if this is your only problem, but that should at least solve one.

You could also use a single output class, with `sigmoid` activation, and `binary_crossentropy`loss. Instead of having two classes 1. "interesting" or 2. "not-interesting" (which is always the inverse of the other). Then you would be training with a single boolean "interesting" [1/0]

You can read more about `softmax`, `sigmoid`, `binary_crossentropy` and `categorical_crossentropy` [here](https://gombru.github.io/2018/05/23/cross_entropy_loss/)

Comment: How to use a single boolean for training ?